# Flutter: How to populate a scrollable widget incrementally until its scrollable

Tags: flutter

My Flutter app includes a search function that can return a large number of results. I therefore retrieve these in a small batch, adding more when the viewport is scrolled (I'm using a Wrap widget in a SingleChildScrollView.

This works fine but I have a problem if the initial batch doesn't fill the viewport on a particular (larger) device and the widget isn't scrollable as a result. This means that I can't get the extra results as this is triggered by scrolling.

What I want to be able to do is keep getting results until the viewport is scrollable.
I can of course increase the batch size so that the largest device is filled but this defeats the purpose of getting small batches.

Comment: One suggestion may be to fill the scroll view with invisible elements such that they take up space in the view but don't contain any content. Then, when the user scrolls, just replace the invisible elements, ensuring a scrollable view.